# Two geodesics in a geodesic ball with the same end points are identical?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian Manifold and let $p\in M$. I was wondering if $c_1, c_2$ are two geodesics in a geodesic ball say $B_c(p)$, (where $B_c(p)$ is defined to be the image of a ball in $T_pM$ under $exp_p$) with the same end points and  having as starting point $p$ then they are identical (where identical means $c_1(t)=c_2(t) $ for every $t$).

Any help? (At least if is it true)

Comment: Please add definition of geodesic ball.

Comment: Indeed, it is true.

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'geodesic ball' and 'identical.'

Comment: With the edit, the answer is: Quite false, even if your manifold is flat.

Comment: Keep in mind that if $c: [0,1]\to M$ is a geodesic from $p$ to $q$ then $c(at), t\in [0, a^{-1}]$ is also a geodesic connecting $p$ to $q$. Such geodesics are said to be **geometrically the same.** As for geometrically distinct geodesics, I suggest to think about the unit sphere and a geodesic ball  of radius $> \pi$.

Comment: @Kohan thank you very much!